# Unable to compile Typescript: property 'getObjectAttributes' is missing in type 'AWS.S3'

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I trying to use multerS3 and AWS-SDK with typescript, however is not working.
"aws-sdk": "^2.1072.0", "multer": "^1.4.4", "multer-s3": "^2.7.8", "@types/multer": "^1.4.4",
"@types/multer-s3": "^2.7.8",

````
        acl: 'public-read',
        s3,
        bucket: `${process.env.AWS_BUCKET}`,
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        key: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(8, (err, hash) => {
                if(err) cb(err);
                const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;
                cb(null, fileName)
            });
        }
    })```

Problem : 
Property 'getObjectAttributes' is missing in type 'AWS.S3' but required in type 'S3'.ts(2741)
s3.d.ts(391, 3): 'getObjectAttributes' is declared here.
index.d.ts(13, 5): The expected type comes from property 's3' which is declared here on type 'Options'

Am I doing something wrong? Basically I follow all the documentation from Amazon and MulterS3 website.
````

Comment: Note that `@types/` packages are from https://definitelytyped.org/ and are typically contributed by the community. They are not always accurate or up-to-date. In addition, AWS SDK documentation can be outdated or incomplete. I have had to look at the typedefs to get the right AWS SDK parameters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.